# How can I use a custom image as BadgeDrawable in a BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable, android-bottomnav

I am showing a badge in a bottomNavigation menu item with this code:

```
val customBadge = bottomNavigation.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.menu_item_id)
customBadge.isVisible = true
```

[image]

**QUESTION:**

Instead using the default badges I would like to use a **custom image** that I imported as `Drawable` resource in my project `R.drawable.custom_badge`.

```
customBadge.setDrawableBadge(R.drawable.custom_badge)

fun setDrawableBadge(drawableResource: Int) {
    // Anyone knows how to implement this?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the [expected answer](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/826#issuecomment-712316559) but currently (`1.3.0-alpha03`)

> Right now, we are intentionally not opening support for customizing the shape of a badge drawable because our designers are doing usability studies on how to expand badges to support more use cases.